# reloadReactNative() is acting different from ios to android

Tags: detox

I have two tests:

```
describe('Example', () => {
beforeEach(async () => {
await device.reloadReactNative();
});

it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
await Login.setUsername(username);
await Login.setPassword(password);
await Login.clickLogin();
});

it('second test', async () => {
await Login.setUsername(username);
await Login.setPassword(password);
await Login.clickLogin();
});

});
```

After each test on android app starts in login screen but on ios starts in next screen after login.
What i-m missing here? i assume that reloadReactNative() is acing different
p.s. i'm new to Detox so i'm in exploring phase.

Running on simulators: iphone 11 pro/x with ios 14/12.2, Android simulator with a9

```
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"jest-circus": "^26.4.2",
"detox": "^17.6.0",
"react-native": "~0.62.2",
```

Comment: You can't probably imagine how challenging it is to tell without looking inside the actual app. It might be a bug, but also might be some quirk in your app or a third-party library as well. Examine Detox code in Kotlin and Swift, and compare what is different about `reloadReactNative` implementation between the platforms.  That might give you the further clues.

Comment: it was a bug inside the app; thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Bug inside of the application. On android credentials were kept for some reason.